# solving limits with trig

Tags: calculus

How do i solve the below without using L'hopital rule. The final answer obtained is $2/3$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\cot\frac{2}{n}+n\csc\frac{3}{n^2}}}{\displaystyle{\csc\frac{3}{n}+n\cot\frac{2}{n^2}}}$$

How do i go about solving using limit of 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0,\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$$

I was shown to this step but how do i get to it?
[image]

I can't understand how the substitution works an example is (3/n^2)/*sin3/n^2)*1/3 .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, the author of the solution divided the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\cot\frac{2}{n}+n\csc\frac{3}{n^2}}}{\displaystyle{\csc\frac{3}{n}+n\cot\frac{2}{n^2}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n^3}\left(\cot\frac{2}{n}+n\csc\frac{3}{n^2}\right)}}{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n^3}\left(\csc\frac{3}{n}+n\cot\frac{2}{n^2}\right)}}$$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{2n^2}\cot\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{3n^2}\csc\frac{3}{n^2}}}{\displaystyle{\frac{3}{n}\frac{1}{3n^2}\csc\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{2n^2}\cot\frac{2}{n^2}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{\tan \frac{2}{n}}\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{\frac{3}{n^2}}{\sin\frac{3}{n^2}}\frac{1}{3}}}{\displaystyle{\frac{\frac{3}{n}}{\sin\frac{3}{n}}\frac{1}{3n^2}+\frac{\frac{2}{n^2}}{\tan\frac{2}{n^2}}}\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: I see, your right about it

Comment: I see, i thought it should be n/(sin(3/n^2) * n^2/3 for the example fraction on the right. Still can't understand how this trig limit works. Any reason why he divide by n^3 for all instead of working part by part? When i tried to work part by part i get 0 for every fractions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle{\cot\frac{2}{n}+n\csc\frac{3}{n^2}}}{\displaystyle{\csc\frac{3}{n}+n\cot\frac{2}{n^2}}}\\
\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\tan\frac{2}{n}}+\frac{n}{\sin\frac{3}{n^2}}}{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{3}{n}}+\frac{n}{\tan\frac{2}{n^2}}}\\
\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3(\frac{1}{\tan\frac{2}{n}}+\frac{n}{\sin\frac{3}{n^2}})}{n^3(\frac{1}{\sin\frac{3}{n}}+\frac{n}{\tan\frac{2}{n^2}})}$$ Then you can get the desired result.

Comment: for this kind of trig limit question, how do you find what value should be used for division

Comment: You have to do it in reverse way. First take the arguments of tan and sin then simplify it to find out what you need extra...

Comment: for example, the argument of tan is 2/n^2 so i would need it in the numerator and also in the denominator to cancel them out. Just can't figure out how the 1/n^3 came about